# Can not run 'npm start' ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yeoman

I'm new in ReactJS nad Yeoman generator. Soo I have a problem, becasue when I generate project with this command

1. npm install -g yo
2. npm install -g generator-react-webpack
3. yo react-webpack

Then I set up project name, use css, and enable postcss. 
When I try to use commend 
npm start # or npm run serve

4. npm run serve

   > @0.0.1 serve C:\Users\user\Desktop\ProjectReact
   >   node server.js --env=dev

   ```
   events.js:183
         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
         ^

   Error: listen EACCES 127.0.0.1:8000
       at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
       at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
       at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1338:19)
       at listenInCluster (net.js:1396:12)
       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1505:7)
       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:97:10)
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! @0.0.1 serve: `node server.js --env=dev`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the @0.0.1 serve script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-25T07_27_23_660Z-debug.log
   ```

Comment: The port is already taken, if you're running windows then check task manager and end all node processes.

Comment: Oh yeah it was so simply Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The port you are using to run the node application in your server.js file is 8000 which is already taken and some other process is running on it.

You can either kill the current running process on 8000 port or change the port in your `server.js` file to something else than *8000* port. and try running again.